# Возможно ли превратить список/кортеж в словарь таким образом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сам вопрос:

Есть список или кортеж: graph.

```
graph = ((0,10,0,30,100), (0,0,50,0,0), (0,0,0,0,10), (0,0,20,0,60), (0,0,0,0,0))
```

Или

```
graph = [[0,10,0,30,100], [0,0,50,0,0], [0,0,0,0,10], [0,0,20,0,60], [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Я хочу создать словарь, чтобы воспользоваться Алгоритмом Дейкстры. Словарь должен иметь следующий вид - { вершина: [(стоимость пути, путь к вершине)] }.

```
graph = {
    0: [(10, 1), (30, 3), (100, 4)],
    1: [(50, 2)],
    2: [(10, 4)],
    3: [(20, 2), (60, 4)],
    4: [(None, None)]
}
```

Как мне это сделать? Не понимаю. Новичок.

И дополнительный вопрос к вам: правильно ли я понимаю, что ключ [4] будет иметь значение (None, None)? Если вершина [4] никуда не идет.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста что из кортежа является вершиной, стоимостью пути и путём к вершине.

Comment: Получается так: ```(Сам граф или матрица)graph = (первая вершина(путь к вершине 1, путь к вершине 2, путь к вершине 3, ..., путь к вершине n) и т.д.)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Легко. Всё довольно линейно делается, если использовать словарное и списковое сокращение, а также enumerate:

```
d = {i: [(y,j) for j,y in enumerate(x) if y] or [(None,None)] for i,x in enumerate(graph)}
```

Результат в d:

```
{0: [(10, 1), (30, 3), (100, 4)],
 1: [(50, 2)],
 2: [(10, 4)],
 3: [(20, 2), (60, 4)],
 4: [(None, None)]}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Он работает. Но для закрепления знания задам вопрос: правильно я понимаю? вы задали переменную, в котором задается список кортежей из двух элементов, и он считает каждую вершину и его путь?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю метод enumerate(). Почему он не брал во внимание нулевые значения?

Comment: Аааа, вроде понял. Потому что есть условие если у истинно? То есть имеет не нулевое значение?

Comment: Насчёт вершин ничего не знаю, я работал просто как с коллекциями цифр. А нулевые значения отсекаются тут с помощью условия `if y` в списковом сокращении.